# ```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence ```when I run tensorflow project

Tags: tensorflow

```
  File "model_VQA.py", line 279, in train
    tf_loss, tf_image, tf_question, tf_label = model.build_model()
  File "model_VQA.py", line 53, in build_model
    state = tf.zeros([self.batch_size, self.stacked_lstm.state_size])
  File "/home/xus/.virtualenvs/vqa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1359, in zeros
...

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`

```
 # question-embedding
    self.embed_ques_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([self.vocabulary_size, self.input_embedding_size], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_ques_W')#self.vocabulary_size=14470 self.input_embedding_size=200
  # encoder: RNN body
    self.lstm_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_size, input_embedding_size, use_peepholes=True)#rnn_size=512,input_embedding_size=200
    self.lstm_dropout_1 =tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(self.lstm_1, output_keep_prob = 1 - self.drop_out_rate)#self.drop_out_rate=0
    self.lstm_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_size, rnn_size, use_peepholes=True)
    self.lstm_dropout_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(self.lstm_2, output_keep_prob = 1 - self.drop_out_rate)
    self.stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([self.lstm_dropout_1, self.lstm_dropout_2])#state_is_tuple=False)
    # state-embedding
    self.embed_state_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2*rnn_size*rnn_layer, self.dim_hidden], -0.08,0.08),name='embed_state_W')#dim_hidden=1024
    self.embed_state_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([self.dim_hidden], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_state_b')
    # image-embedding
    self.embed_image_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([dim_image, self.dim_hidden], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_image_W')#dim_image=4096
    self.embed_image_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([dim_hidden], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_image_b')
    # score-embedding
    self.embed_scor_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([dim_hidden, num_output], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_scor_W')#num_output=1000
    self.embed_scor_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_output], -0.08, 0.08), name='embed_scor_b')
def build_model(self):
    image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.dim_image])
    question = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.batch_size, self.max_words_q])
    label = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [self.batch_size,])
    state = tf.zeros([self.batch_size, self.stacked_lstm.state_size])#self.batch_size=500
```

`thanx~
Anyone can tell me what cause this error ？I am doing a VQA project,this code is from github  and the link is https://github.com/JamesChuanggg/VQA-tensorflow/blob/master/model_VQA.py

Comment: How about showing the code that ran into this error? The problem is either in the code or in the data.

Comment: thanx~,I have  post  the code.

Comment: It's kind of you to help me.

Comment: What are `type(self.batch_size)` and `type(self.stacked_lstm.state_size)`?

Comment: thanks~after check it I found I forgot to reshape the input.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inputs you are feeding into your model (the dataset and labels). The value error is likely to be caused by one or more of the inputs being of the wrong shape. I suggest printing your inputs and making sure they are all arrays of the correct dimensions. If you need further help, attaching your code to your question will help us pinpoint the problem more precisely.

Comment: It‘s very kind of you to help me.